# Create a line over the object Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have object on my floor I need to create a line over it
I am aware how to add a geometry to autodesk viewer but I am stuck with how to I get the geometry or the shape of existing object so that I can add a line with same shape over it

till now with my understanding
I am able to get mesh of that object using db id using which I have world matix and world bound

and I am sure the solutions lies around this but not sure how to use it

here is how my floor line looks like

Blue Line is Floor and Need to add a yellow Line over it, right now to show a sample I have added yellow line using Paint
[image]

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, the blue line in the screenshot is an actual part of your Forge model? And you are trying to generate a custom three.js poly-line that follows the blue path?

Comment: yes exactly what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the geometry of a specific element in your Forge model using the `FragmentList` structure:

```js
function listTriangles(geometry) {
    console.log('Triangle count', geometry.polyCount);
    const stride = geometry.vbstride;
    const vbPositionOffset = geometry.attributes.position.itemOffset;
    for (let tri = 0; tri < geometry.polyCount; tri++) {
        let i1 = geometry.ib[tri * 3],
            i2 = geometry.ib[tri * 3 + 1],
            i3 = geometry.ib[tri * 3 + 2];
        let v1 = new THREE.Vector3(
            geometry.vb[i1 * stride + vbPositionOffset],
            geometry.vb[i1 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 1],
            geometry.vb[i1 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 2]
        );
        let v2 = new THREE.Vector3(
            geometry.vb[i2 * stride + vbPositionOffset],
            geometry.vb[i2 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 1],
            geometry.vb[i2 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 2]
        );
        let v3 = new THREE.Vector3(
            geometry.vb[i3 * stride + vbPositionOffset],
            geometry.vb[i3 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 1],
            geometry.vb[i3 * stride + vbPositionOffset + 2]
        );
        console.log('Triangle vertices', v1, v2, v3);
    }
}

function listMeshes(model, dbid) {
    const tree = model.getInstanceTree();
    const frags = model.getFragmentList();
    tree.enumNodeFragments(dbid, function (fragid) {
        let mesh = frags.getVizmesh(fragid); // Note: the mesh object will be reused next time we call getVizmesh!
        listTriangles(mesh.geometry);
    }, true);
}
```

Note that this will just give you the individual triangles, their vertices, etc. If you want to somehow map the list of triangles into a poly line, that would be a non-trivial task that would require some computational graphics expertise.

Comment: thanks petr let me put this on test, also could guide me how can I find the Start and End of this object ? Ie End Position and Start Position so that I can do a setview with that points

Comment: That's the tricky part Ronak. The geometry you get from the Forge model is just a list of triangles (with three xyz vertices for each triangle), it doesn't really have any "start" or "end". It would be up to you to somehow compute the "start" and "end" from that data.